# Is this proof for inverse transform method valid for any pdf?

Tags: statistics, proof-verification, random, simulation

This is from a uni course that includes a chapter about simulation, and introduces this method for random number generation.

While the theorem is about a general $f(x)$ (probability density function), it seems to me the proof assumes an uniform distribution, and therefore it's valid only for that. Am I wrong? Is this particular proof valid for any probability density function?

Theorem and proof:

[image]

Comment: As the statement and proof state, the method allows you to obtain a randomvariable with the desired pdf from a random variable with uniform distribution.

Comment: Don't confuse $X$ and $Y$: You want to generate samples from an arbitrary distribution $f_X(x)$. For this, you use a second random variable $Y$, which is (and needs to be) uniform. One could extend this further for nonuniform $Y$, but there is no good reason to do so. Or can you name one?

Comment: A uniform distribution is indeed assumed in the proof but this for the *auxiliary* random variable $Y$. It is proved then that $F^{-1}(Y)$ has PDF $f$, exactly as promised.

Comment: The proof there works if $F$ is strictly increasing. But a more general version of using 'generalized inverse' of $F$ exists.

Comment: Thanks to all of you, thanks to your answers and a more careful reading i understand now the assumption is just on the auxiliary variable.

Comment: Many distributions do not have a simply stated quantile function or inverse of the CDF $F^{-1}$

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In practice, the catch is that the inverse of the CDF is not known in a convenient form for some random variables.

Because this is a result widely used in computer simulation, maybe it will
help to see how it works in practice. I will use R statistical
software. Function `runif` samples from a uniform distribution;
`qexp` is the inverse CDF (quantile) function of an exponential
distribution.

The code below samples 100,000 observations from an
exponential distribution with mean 10 (rate 0.1). For such a
large sample there is pretty good fit of the histogram of the sample to the PDF of the population.

```
m = 10^5;  r = runif(m, 0, 1)  # vector of 100,000 from UNIF(0,1)
x = qexp(r, .1)  # random sample of 100,000 obs from EXP(rate=0,1)
hdr = "Histogram of Sample from EXP(1/10) with Density Fcn"
hist(x, prob=T, br=60, ylim=c(0,.1), col="skyblue2", main=hdr)
  curve(dexp(x, .1), add=T, lwd=2, col="red", n = 1001)
```

[image]

*Note:* For this example, you can write the CDF of the exponential distribution, find its inverse,
and write explicit mathematics to match the simulation.

**Addendum** on sampling from a normal population (per @Henry's Comment).  The CDF $\Phi(\cdot)$ of a standard normal distribution is not available in 'closed form' and so neither is its quantile function $\Phi^{-1}(\cdot).$ (Thus the crucial need for printed normal
tables before the computer era.)

However, Michael Wichura (1998) has
constructed rational approximations to both $\Phi(\cdot)$  and $\Phi^{-1}(\cdot),$ which are accurate to the extent expressible by double precision in software. Accordingly, R statistical software uses Wichura's approximation for its `qnorm`. So `qnorm(runif(m))` returns a sample of size `m` from the standard normal distribution. [That is, `qnorm(runif(m))` is equivalent to `rnorm(m)`--except for minor technical tweaks.]

```
set.seed(1234); qnorm(runif(1))  # Pseudo-random number generator...
[1] -1.207066                    #   for reproducibility
set.seed(1234); rnorm(1)         # Start with same PRNG seed...
[1] -1.207066                    #   to get same result with 'rnorm'                  


hist(qnorm(runif(10^5)), prob=T, col="skyblue2", br = 50,
    main="Standard Normal Sample")   
  curve(dnorm(x), add=T, lwd=2, col="red")
```

[image]

*Note:* For this example, you cannot write the CDF of the standard normal distribution. While the theorem in your Question remains valid and useful, this example must remain a computer demonstration.